# Consuming a WCF service from applications with different types of authentication

Tags: c#, wpf, wcf

I have a WCF service and I'm trying to consume it from two WPF applications. First, I have a WPF project with Windows authentication, sending credentials to the WCF service and consuming a DataBase with this credentials. It goes OK:

Connection string:

```
<add name="connection" connectionString="Data Source=....;Initial Catalog=db;Integrated Security=SSPI;Application Name=dbn;Connect Timeout=350;"/>
```

Binding and behavior:

```
<bindings>
  <basicHttpBinding>
    <binding>
      <security mode="Transport">
        <transport clientCredentialType="Basic"/>
      </security>
    </binding>
  </basicHttpBinding>
</bindings>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="false" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
      <serviceAuthorization impersonateCallerForAllOperations="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Behavior of service methods:

```
[OperationBehavior(Impersonation = ImpersonationOption.Allowed)]
```

As I said, it goes OK, but now I want to call this service from another WPF service without authentication, and consume the Data Base with SQL authentication:

Connection string:

```
<add name="sqlconnection" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=..."/>
```

To Call different connectionStrings from methods it's not the problem, but maybe I need different binding or behavior to makes it work. How I can configure that from the WCF service? It is possible?

Comment: I also have WPF-WCF-SQL architecture but your architecture seems bit different..My case is, the middle broker(WCF) only has connectionstring to connect to SQL database. What do you mean by 2 connectionstring from 2 WPF applications?

Comment: WCF app has one connectionstring to connect to the Data Base with Windows authentication, and other with SQL authentication, because one WPF app requires the authentication and the other not.

Comment: I think you'd better specifically ask question at WCF thread of MSDN because Microsoft cares WCF as its own.